# how do you process mdg.php files during an extension upgrade?

Tags: extension

What's the best way to trigger managed entity processing as part of an extension upgrade? I have an extension that is already installed on a site. I'm rolling out an upgrade that implements a new custom report, including the .mgd.php file. I'd like that report template to be installed as part of the extension version upgrade. But I'm not sure the best way to "refresh" the system to process that .mgd.php file (which is generally only processed during installation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think invoking below method in your extensions Upgrader.php incrementalupgrade function will re-build all your managed entities from all extension.

```
CRM_Core_Invoke::rebuildMenuAndCaches();
```